# Feed Me import from CSV ignores decimal point

Tags: localization, plugin-feedme, entries-field, number

I use Feed Me to import values from a .csv file into my entries. Since a day i have an issue i can't explain. I didn't change anything.
Precisely, the issue concerns a number field.
In the .csv file, i have, for example, the value 769.00.
Then i import this value with Feed Me and get the value 76900 in the number field. The decimal point gets ignored:

[image]

Here's the csv row:
Artikelnummer,Bestellnummer1,Artikelbezeichnung,Grösse,Farbe,Modelljahr,Notiz,Warengruppe,Hersteller,**VKbrutto**,UVP,Lagerbestand,Reserviert,Bestellt

18128,S20TONR2716,Stevens Tonga 27.5" Disc Shim. Alivio 22 Gang,16",Fire Red,2020,,Mountainbike,Stevens Bikes,**769.00**,,1,0,0

It's the same problem as here: https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/443

My website language is: de-CH

Can anyone give me a hint where this issue comes from?

Comment: Can you post a sample row from your CSV?

Comment: put a link to a sample of my csv into the question. It's about the column "J".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the Craft Support Team, i solved this problem for me.
Two ways to solve this:

1. Change Number field to text field.
2. Change Language under users/user/preferences/language from Deutsch to english.